# Responsive divs toruble

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries, media

I am new to responsive design and I'm taking my first shot at it with a blog I am making for my company. I am using media queries to change the width % and float of the divs that are going to serve as my blog articles. All of my queries are working great except for this one...

```
@media only screen
and (min-width: 1196px) 
and (max-width: 1667px) {

#Blog1, #Blog2, #Blog3 ,#Blog4, #Blog5, #Blog6, #Blog7, #Blog8, #Blog9 ,#Blog10, #Blog11,           
#Blog12, #Blog13, #Blog14, #Blog15 ,#Blog16, #Blog17, #Blog18, #Blog19, #Blog20, #Blog21,  
#Blog22, #Blog23, #Blog24, #Blog25 ,#Blog26, #Blog27, #Blog28, #Blog29, #Blog30, #Blog31,
#Blog32, #Blog33, #Blog34, #Blog35 ,#Blog36, #Blog37, #Blog38, #Blog39,#Blog40, #Blog41,
#Blog42, #Blog43, #Blog44, #Blog45 ,#Blog46, #Blog47, #Blog48, #Blog49
{
float:left;
margin-left:2.5%;
margin-right:2.5%;
margin-top:2%;
margin-bottom:2%;
width:30%;
}
}
```

I'm trying to tell it to spread three blog posts across the screen evenly. It works when you get to the size of an iPad (1024px-768px) and it spreads two divs across the screen evenly but it will not work when I ask it to do the same for 3 divs. Instead, it pushes the 3rd div to the next row. I have tried different display: properties but to no avail.

You can view the example here: [www.highlandplanning.com/blog.html](http://www.highlandplanning.com/blog/html)     - but you need a big screen to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider making the margins or the width smaller. With margins it'll come to 35% and 35% doesn't fit into 100% 3 times.